# how to use 0p.in to search the array of objects?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

To explain better what I need, I start with what I have. I have a table with a simple primary key - and when I am deleting records, I pass to the function the array of IDs which need to be deleted. Subsequently, I use this sequelize query to determine which records need to be deleted

```
const where: any = { id: { [Op.in]: deleteIds } };
```

What changed? I need to use composite primary key for the table, so I no more pass the array of strings to the table, but the array of objects with several properties, let's say looking like this

```
[ {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2 
}, {
    prop1: value2,
    prop2: value3 
} ]
```

And deleted shall be only those records, where both properties fit. Could someone advise how to do it? I was thinking about something like this, but it doesn't work. I feel that I need to make sure that not only both values (of the object going to be deleted) need to be present in an array, but both need to be related to a single object. Thank you

```
{
 $and: [
   { column1: { [Op.in]: deleteIds.prop1 } },
   { column2: { [Op.in]: deleteIds.prop2 } },
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine `Op.and` (implicitly defined by an object with props) and `Op.or` to make it work:

```js
{
 [Op.or]: deleteIds.map(x => ({
   column1: x.prop1,
   column2: x.prop2,
 }))
}
```

Comment: hello, thank you, looks interesting. So you basically copy all objects in the array into another array and browse through it with 0p.or function?

Comment: I turned an array of ids into an array of objects each stores AND conditions and all of objects will be joined by OR